# Using prompt answer for conditional formatting in Microstrategy

Tags: dashboard, microstrategy

I'd like to know whether or not its possible to use a prompt answer as a condition to conditionally format ( hide or display) an object ( a text box ) in a Microstrategy document.

All help is appreciated

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use directly the prompt answer (I assume you where trying to use `{&PROMPT1&}`, because this was also what I tried to do in the past), but you can use the result of a dataset that contains that prompt as condition for your conditional formatting. Of course this method has limitation.

When I had to show/hide few labels (text boxes) depending on the values of a prompt, I used an attribute element prompt and then I used that attribute in my conditional formatting. The limitation is that my prompt accepted only a single answer.

I think it's possible to do something similar also with a value prompt, but you need to have a metric that returns the value of that prompt and then use that metric in the condition.